# Speeding up rspec by deleting tmp files (or any of this sort?)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, testing, rspec

I'm looking to speed up our rails application tests. We're already around 600 tests, it's  getting higher and it's starting to take a long time to run.

I know there are some tools to speed up the tests. Some we are already using, some we will start using, and im quite sure some we can't use due to our rails version (2.3.8).

But I came here for a different reason. Few weeks ago, I started using a computer that didn't run our tests for a while, and the tests run really really fast. Instead of taking the usual 20-30 minutes, it was completed within 5-7 minutes, if not less.

At first I thought something is wrong, but the more times I run - it started to become slower and slower until it took me 20-30 minutes to run, again.

Now the tests were the same tests, tools were and are the same. I can't think off anything dramatically that changed, besides the fact that I haven't run the tests for a while (few weeks~) and then run again. Could it be something related to tmp files or any of this sort that can be deleted or tweaked to get our tests to run faster?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Some tips to speed up testing:

- Make sure you are using transactional fixtures
- Try only initializing instead of persisting objects in the database
- put `config.whiny_nils = false` on your `config/environments/test.rb`
- If you're using Devise, put `config.stretches = Rails.env.test? ? 1 : 10` on your `config/initializers/devise.rb`
- Upgrade to 1.9.3

PS: Just saw you're using Rails 2.3.8, so this won't work for you, but I'll leave it here in case someone wants to use:

- Put [this patch](https://gist.github.com/1437939) into your application (be sure to remove it when upgrading to 3.2)

Comment: Thanks for your help but can you please help me regarding my specific question?

Comment: He did. You didn't provide enough information for anything more specific.

Comment: I was asking if the test's runtime could be related to any temp files/logs etc that could be deleted. If this is not enough information - could you please tell me what more information I should add? thanks.

Comment: Well, try deleting them and see if it helps -- Although I find it really hard tmp files to be the culprit.

Comment: It doesn't have to be the tmp files or the log. All im saying is that  I noticed quite some difference from the first time I run the tests to the 15th time. Thought it might be something, but could also be nothing.